# How much of a flat slope is acceptable when using floating LVP?

Tags: flooring

Is a 1/4" slope over an 8' length hallway too much for floating LVP ~ the floor is completely flat but it slopes towards the back door.  The LVP seams will run across the hallway, not lengthwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flooring only cares about flatness.

People care if the slope can be felt.  Your slope is about 1/32 of an inch over a foot.  Doubt if you can even tell without good measurement.

The work to fix it is not worth it, unless doing it for a perfectionist.

Flooring does care(not like) any dips/hills/ridges on the floor.  Those do need to be fixed first.

Comment: The floor is flat, with no dips, hills or ridges, so it sounds like we're okay.

Answer (score 4):

Slope means nothing to flooring until you get so steep that it threatens to tear it loose from the subfloor. This isn't a structural concern whatsoever. Most people won't even detect that much.

Answer (score 3):

That slope shouldn't matter for LVP.  Even for a floating floor, that isn't anywhere near drastic enough to cause the finished floor to move or slide.

edit:  I initially read the slope as 1/4" *per foot* rather than over the entire distance.  I'd actually consider that close enough to a flat floor in residential construction.

Comment: Yeah, unless you're setting up for a silicone chip fab plant, I think most people would call 1/4" over 8' both "flat" and "level".